# Execute a powershell command from batch

Tags: windows, batch, powershell, batch-file

I need to split up a very long line in a text file (maybe hundrerd thousands of characters) into shorter lines (8184 characters) and a `.bat` cannot handle this task.

However, I found a PowerShell solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248726/how-can-i-insert-a-carriage-return-linefeed-every-x-characters-with-notepad)):

```
(gc in.txt) -replace ".{750}" , "$&`r`n" | sc out.txt
```

---

This works when I open up the PowerShell window and paste the slightly adjusted version, where `750` is `8184` and execute it, BUT when including it in my `.bat` like this ...:

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '.{8184}' , '$&`r`n' | sc temp.txt"
```

... it doesn't work as intended and inserts ...

```
`r`n
```

... after every 8184th character (I cannot inline format this, sry).

---

I tried to make use of:

```
powershell -Command "& {(gc test.txt) -replace '.{8184}' , '$&`r`n' | sc temp.txt}"

powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '.{8184}' , '$&\r\n' | sc temp.txt"

powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '.{8184}' , '$&VbCrLf' | sc temp.txt"
```

But I'm unable to make it work. What is the problem here?

Comment: Just so I'm clear here, you have a very long line in a text file, and you want to split it into shorter lines and save it to another file?

Comment: @rahuldottech Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`` `r`n `` is the correct escape sequence for a newline, but the problem is that single-quoted strings don't do the escape sequence evaluation or variable interpolation that double-quoted strings do, hence the literal escape sequence ending up in your output. We need to pass the string to PowerShell double-quoted, which is somewhat tricky since we have to deal with `cmd.exe`'s interpretation as well. Using four double quotes per understood double quote does the job:

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '.{8184}' , """"$&`r`n"""" | sc temp.txt"
```

Comment: How would I undo this with PowerShell itself? I tried several solutions I found and none of them appear to work...

Comment: @FatalBulletHit `((gc .\linebroken.txt) -join '') | sc .\oneline.txt` should put it all back on one line.